# How to change div background onclick with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I want the background of the `div` changed where the button is in. Now it changes all at same time and I know why, but I don't know how I can make them work on their own.

When I press the "yes" button in server1, I want the background color of server 1 to be red and when I press the button again, it has to be the original color again. I don't mind if the script is totally different, but I would like to keep the HTML.

```js
    // var white = false
    // var bgcolor;
    // $("button ,yes").click(function () {
    //     if (white = !white) {
    //         bgcolor = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    //         $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    //     } else {
    //         $(this).css("background-color", bgcolor);
    //     }
    // });

    var green = false
    function toggleStatus()
    {
        if (green = !green)
        {
             $("#maindiv .serverstatus ").each(function ()
            {
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#maindiv .serverstatus").each(function ()
            {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#639919");
            });
        }
    };

    // function updateStatus(){
    //     $("#maindiv .serverstatus").each(function(){
    //         $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    //     });
    // }
    //
    // $( document ).ready(function() {
    //     updateStatus();
    // });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Grafiek</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Server Stats</h1>
<div id="maindiv">
    <div id="server1" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername1)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>

        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus()">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="server2" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername2)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus()">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="server3" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername3)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus()">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "green = !green" isn't valid JavaScript.  I assume you mean something along the lines of "green !== green" which will always be false.  You're comparing boolean false to false for inequality.

Comment: toggle a class on the element

Comment: Are you want to change background of `serverstatus` when clicked in their own button `yes`?

Comment: when i press the button in div id=server1 i want that background to change

Comment: That sounds curious : ) But how are you identifying the green logic? Is it just a logical switcher here ? Because, with jQuery we can conditionnally toggle css classes in a better way... How are you initiating your server "status"? is it from a database?

Comment: @Bilel then how would u do it im open for anyyhing as long as it changes the div background on press of the button and not yet thats my final plan

Comment: If you your page is initiated the same way it's being mentioned in your code @NathanChampion ' answer does the job. Otherwise, if colors are initiated differently in your project, and loading differently, you better toggle classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried keeping things as close to original as possible.  I've also removed any JQuery code so unless you need it elsewhere you can remove that reference to trim the page a bit.

I've replaced **toggleStatus()** with toggleStatus(**this**) so it passes the element (a button in this case) so it can be referenced in the function.

Since your HTML structure is laid out this way:

```
<div id="server1" class="serverstatus"> <!-- This would be the button's parentNode.parentNode -->
    <h3>(servername1)</h3>
    <div>
    <button onclick="toggleStatus(this)">yes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Going up the parent/child tree twice will grab the server# div.  That is what is compared in the if/else statement inside the following JavaScript:

```js
    function toggleStatus(e)
    {
      var parentDiv = e.parentNode.parentNode;
      var bgColor = parentDiv.style.backgroundColor;
     
      if(bgColor == "green"){
        parentDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      else{
        parentDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }      
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Grafiek</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Server Stats</h1>
<div id="maindiv">
    <div id="server1" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername1)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>

        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus(this)">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="server2" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername2)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus(this)">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="server3" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername3)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus(this)">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I updated your code with below steps (only changed your code to become working with solution, didnt do the cleanup and refactoring):

1. `toggleStatus` function is now accepting `server_name` and `color_name`
   two parameters
2. `toggleStatus` function definition updated to change
   the background color for passed `server_name`

**Steps done to change it back on clicking again (based on feedback in comment):**

1. create three `css classes` with name of your colors to give background
   color of same name
2. update `toggleStatus` function to toggle the `css class` of `color_name`

```js
    // var white = false
    // var bgcolor;
    // $("button ,yes").click(function () {
    //     if (white = !white) {
    //         bgcolor = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    //         $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    //     } else {
    //         $(this).css("background-color", bgcolor);
    //     }
    // });

    var green = false
    function toggleStatus(server_name,color_name)
    {
        //$('#'+server_name).css("background-color", color_name);
        $('#'+server_name).toggleClass(color_name);
    };

    // function updateStatus(){
    //     $("#maindiv .serverstatus").each(function(){
    //         $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    //     });
    // }
    //
    // $( document ).ready(function() {
    //     updateStatus();
    // });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Grafiek</title>
    <style>
        .red{
          background-color:red;
         }
         .blue{
          background-color:blue;
         }        
         .green{
          background-color:green;
         }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Server Stats</h1>
<div id="maindiv">
    <div id="server1" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername1)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>

        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus('server1','red')">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="server2" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername2)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus('server2','green')">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="server3" class="serverstatus">
        <h3>(servername3)</h3>
        <div>
            Status:
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            Last Checked:
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Online:
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="toggleStatus('server3','blue')">yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works but how do i change the color back to the original color when pressing that button again?

Comment: Yes It doesn't toggle ! You could use his logical switcher as an argument and based on that you choose which color to apply...

Comment: @DamianBloemhof, updated the answer and added two steps for explaination

Comment: @kewlashu im sorry im new to this and i dont really know how i should do that can u maybe provide a little bit of css ?

Comment: @DamianBloemhof, you can find the css added between `<style> </style>` tags in the code of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure if I should be doing your homework, but here is a (not optimal) solution. I would change you HTML too, but I leave that up to you.

This will set all to green and the clicked one to red. There are more elegant solutions

```
function toggleStatus(e) {
    $("#maindiv .serverstatus").each(function ()
        {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#639919");
        });

    $(e).parent().parent().css("background-color", "#ff0000");
};
```

Comment: well it isnt homework its a project im working on but thanks but should i replace the current function with this?

Comment: Yes you can replace it with this, if it meets the required functionality of course. Just try it out.